# Is there any way to get a specific version of a model in laravel backpack-crud?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack, revisionable

I'm using VentureCraft/revisionable for laravel-backpack-curd, I know it helps me to manage a model's change history, but I want to switch to a specific version of a model and get it completely as a model. is there any way to do this?

Let me explain more with an example:
suppose we have a model called TODO I want to fetch different versions of it. Imagine I want to fetch something like this:

```
TODO::find(1)->revision(REVISION_NUMBER)->get();
```

Comment: Care to share some code (as in what you have now vs. what you are expecting to be)?

Comment: @Tpojka I've added more explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using : https://github.com/laravel-backpack/revise-operation (that use VentureCraft/revisionable). Or the https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable with a backpack CRUD project ?

For what I know, the revisions are saved per field in a model that has the revisionable trait.

The [trait](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable/blob/master/src/Venturecraft/Revisionable/RevisionableTrait.php) `VentureCraft/revisionable` doesn't include a scope to narrow et get the value per, as you would like (`->revision`).

To achieve that, you should implement a function on your model to switch the model value to a revision id.

Like (roughly) :

```php
public function previewAsRevision($revision_id) {
  // 1. Get the current model's field values.
  // 2. Get the target revision by $id to get the field modified and both old and new value.
  // 3. temporary change the $this->$field_name value to the revision value.
  // 4. return the temporary Model object with the modified value.
  //kindish and depends on what are the operations needed to be done with this.
}
```

To implement this as a `scope`, it's different. Because each field change creates a new revision entry.

Maybe you would like to see which Todo as its origin values and its currents. That would be possible, since we can get each field that has a revision, and rewind back to the first `oldValue`.

Anyhow, hopes this help or narrow the solution for you.